# MYSQL: How to define or get LONG string variables

Tags: mysql, variables

I am running the following query:

## Variables

```
SET @src = 'Test';
SET @tgt = 'Test2';
SET @db  = 'Test';
SET @pk  = 'ID, MyPk, etc';

SELECT CONCAT( @pk, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT( ", ", COLUMN_NAME) SEPARATOR "") )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @db
AND TABLE_NAME = @src
INTO @cols;
```

## Sample

```
SET @sql = CONCAT( 'INSERT INTO `', @tgt, '` (SELECT ', @cols, ' FROM `', @src, '`);' );
PREPARE stm FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stm;
```

It works...with small tables and I can use this @cols for multiple purposes. However, it stops working with large tables (Large amount of fields). I noticed it breaks at 1024 characters. It ignores LIMIT. Is there away to get a variable longer than 1024 characters or a way around this problem?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294955/storage-limits-of-mysql-user-defined-variables) on Storage limits of MySQL user-defined variables

Comment: The answer there says that strings can hold 16MB, so it doesn't explain why he's getting cut off at 1K.

Comment: What happens if you just do `SELECT @sql`? Maybe the limit is on the size of prepared statements, not the size of the string

Comment: @Barmar Yes and no. The limit is on the size of the variable. A string with anything longer than 1024 characters (into @cols) gets trimmed.

Comment: @Barmar I was wrong. The limit was being set by GROUP_CONCAT. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Why are you telling me that? I wrote it almost 2 hours ago in my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [result truncated,a MYSQL bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996872/result-truncated-a-mysql-bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = (7*1024);
> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = (50*1024*1024);
> ```

**The root of the problem was the function GROUP_CONCAT**. the documentation says GROUP_CONCAT's `group_concat_max_len` IS LIMITED BY `max_allowed_packet`:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

50% to @echo_me and 50% to @barmar. It has to be done together, otherwise it wont work.

Full code:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = (7*1024);
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = (50*1024*1024);

SET @src = 'Test';
SET @tgt = 'Test2';
SET @db  = 'Test';
SET @pk  = 'ID, MyPk, etc';

SELECT CONCAT( @pk, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT( ", ", COLUMN_NAME) SEPARATOR "") )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @db
AND TABLE_NAME = @src
INTO @cols;
```

Comment: Note that (this was my case at least) you need to close the current mysql connection / client and start another one for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

The limit is on the result of `GROUP_CONCAT()`. You can change this with:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 10000
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, you need to locate your mysql `my.cnf` config file and add or change the max allowed packet:

```
 [mysqld]

 max_allowed_packet = 50M
```

Comment: I am not using php. I am using MySQL/Workbench/Etc,

Comment: I tryed it. I even found out you can do `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=52428800;` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/program-variables.html). But it still did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Just use above solution:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = (7*1024);
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = (50*1024*1024);
```

Then, click in Database; Connect to Database; and create another connection. Run code in this newly created connection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.