# mySql Dynamic Pivot Query with over 3000 columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Good Day,
I'm using a dynamic pivot query to generate a cross tab of product sales by month.  There are just over 3K products so that means over 3k columns.  When I run the query I get an error.  If I limit the number of rows in the original table to under 1586 it runs fine with an output of 16 col, including the 'date' field.  I can't figure this out and need some help! Please see the code and error below:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when PSHDSTK = ''',
      PSHDSTK,
      ''' then MthSales end) AS `',
      PSHDSTK,
      '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  salesbyrow;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT thedate, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM salesbyrow
                                    GROUP BY thedate');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

the error I get is

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM salesbyrow
                                    GROUP BY thedate' at line 2
```

Comment: Won't the output be more manageable if you have 3000 _rows_ and as many _columns_ as you have months?

Comment: It would be but not for my purposes.  I need it for a forecasting algorithm and it requires the data in this wide format.

Comment: OK.  You may have to do the pivoting in application code.  That is, fetch 3 columns: month+product+amount; then do the pivot/crosstab.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be working just fine for me on a small sample.
Are you sure there are no quotes or something that may break your `@sql` string in the `PSHDSTK` column?

Add `SELECT @sql` for debugging purposes before execution of your statement (shown below).

Also, beware of MySQL max size for a string variable and GROUP_CONCAT. But that should become clear when you view your query before executing it.

If GROUP_CONCAT max length is the limit (1024 by default) you should alter the temporary setting (session-scope) for length of it. It's done by:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000 -- to set it to 10 000
```

---

Sample:

```
create table salesbyrow(thedate int, PSHDSTK varchar(2), MthSales int);
insert into salesbyrow(thedate,PSHDSTK,MthSales) 
  values (1, 'a1', 6),(1, 'a2', 5), (1, 'a1', 3);
```

Your code:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when PSHDSTK = ''',
      PSHDSTK,
      ''' then MthSales end) AS `',
      PSHDSTK,
      '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  salesbyrow;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT thedate, ', @sql, ' FROM salesbyrow GROUP BY thedate');
```

Sanity check the `@sql` variable:

```
select @sql;
```

Statement looks like this (correct):

```
SELECT thedate, max(case when PSHDSTK = 'a1' then MthSales end) AS `a1`,max(case when PSHDSTK = 'a2' then MthSales end) AS `a2` FROM salesbyrow GROUP BY thedate
```

Now executing ...

```
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

Result:

```
thedate     a1  a2
1           6   5
```

Comment: I think that you may be right.  When I increase the size of the product names (column names) my 1586 threshold goes down.  Running a length@sql) gives me a limit at 1134.  What is the max size on a string variable?  Any suggestions on getting around this...provided that this is the issue?

Comment: Review the @sql variable after it's initialization with GROUP_CONCAT. I believe your columns may not fit there. Check [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722623/mysql-how-to-define-or-get-long-string-variables)

Answer (score 1):

'Consider me' directed me to what was causing the error and another Stackoverflow post directed me to the solution. stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/…;. So I increased the SET SESSION group_concat_max_len and that works great! No need for additional coding.  I just added.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 250000;
```

To the top of the query. Works great! I'm fairly new here so I couldn't up vote 'consider me' who really answered the question of what was causing the issue.